# Obtain file name after Application.DocumentBeforeSave fires

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document that users typically save via a macro that auto-names the files.  Occasionally, I want users to be able to create their own file names.  But, when they do this I want to make sure that the name they are choosing meets certain requirements.  What I need is a way to before save check the file name they chose.

I've looked into [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838299(v=office.14).aspx) but it doesn't apply in my case. The event fires before the file naming dialogue box even appears.   How can I halt the save process and check the name?

Comment: In the event handler you can open your own SaveAs dialog, check the name, save the document, and set `Cancel`..

Comment: How would I differentiate between a user generated save attempt and a macro initiated? I want the user to be able to use the auto-name/save feature as well without showing a dialogue box for that

Comment: Prompt the dialog according to the value of the `SaveAsUI` parameter?